# Enviar una imagen en base64 por post y hacer decode en php

Tags: php, android, laravel, bitmap

Estoy tratando de enviar una imagen desde Android a mi servidor, la imagen la estoy enviando por *HttpRequest* en formato base64, esto dado que no pude enviarla como archivo (si se sabe como enviar un archivo por httprequest en método post me ayudaría mas). La forma en la que hago la conversión es la siguiente:

```
public static String getBase64FromPath(String path) {
    String base64 = "";
    try {/*from   w w w .  ja  va  2s  .  c om*/
        File file = new File(path);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length() + 100];
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        int length = new FileInputStream(file + "/pet_image.jpg").read(buffer);
        base64 = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, 0, length,
                Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64;
}
```

Por otro lado en el servidor que tengo corriendo el backend, esto funciona pero parcialmente, dado que al intentar ver la imagen en el servidor la imagen se carga parcialmente.

```
 public function upload_image_app(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(), [
            'type' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) return Response::json($validator->messages(), 406);
    try {
        $filename = $this->name_for_file();
        $image = $request->image;  // your base64 encoded
        $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
        Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, base64_decode($image));
        $upload = new Image;
        $upload->filename = $filename;
        $upload->type = $request->type;
        $upload->pet = $request->pet;
        $upload->user()->associate(auth()->user());
        $upload->save();

        return Response::json('image created -> ' . $filename , 200);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return Response::json('failed to create image', 500);
    }
}
```

asi se ve la imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No conozco de android, pero claro que te evitarías todo ese manejo en el backend si pudieses enviar la imagen como un archivo binario. De todas formas, aunque veo que ya estas haciendo un str_replace de los espacios vacíos por el signo +, podría ser que quede algún espacio o caracter que haga que la imagen se corte ahí. ¿Podrías mostrar un dump de lo que te llega en `$request->image` y mostrarlo? Prueba con una imagen pequeña para que no sea muy largo

Comment: Logre enviar la imagen como archivo completo en jpeg, ahora solo tengo arreglar el detalle de la calidad, pierdo calidad al enviarlo así, veré que recibo en el request, revisaré el replace porque así mismo no lo revierto en el backend y lo acabo de notar